# How to extract directory properties in Windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, file, winapi

Does any function return how many files are in a directory?

Is the only way to iterate through all files?

(For example, when you right click the directory in windows, it lists: `7 files in directory`. Is there a way to extract that information?, how is "it" getting that info?)

Thanks.

Comment: the directory class might helt http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx#Y0

Comment: @weberik: if he was using a .NET language, it might, but according to the tags, he's asking about C and C++ neither of which is (apparently yet another case of confusion between C++ and C++/CLI, which is almost, but not quite, completely unlike C++). What Microsoft labels as "C++" in the linked page applies to C++/CLI, not to C++.

Comment: you are right. just noticed that there is a serperate tag for "managed c++"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if there's a better way, but I use FindFirstFile/FindNextFile to do this (some error checking removed for clarity):

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
_TCHAR szDir[] = _T("somedir\\*");

hFind = FindFirstFile(szDir, &ffd);

do
{
    if((ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) && !(!_tcscmp(ffd.cFileName,_T(".")) || !_tcscmp(ffd.cFileName, _T(".."))))
    {
        // This is a directory
    }
}
while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `FindFirstFile` / `FindNextFile` Win32 API functions to iterate through the files in the directory and count how many there are. There is no single statistic that is maintained at a directory level.

Windows Explorer does something similar at the lowest level.